# JavaScript auto type writer function

Tags: javascript, arrays, dom-events

I'm having an issue with a automatic typing function that I have created for this website. Everything  works great but when it finish going thru my array of words it move the page up then when it starts again it moves the page down. I want the page to stay in place when it finish the array of words as well as when it starts the array of words.

```js
var messages=["Your word is a lamp to my feet and a light to my path.","","Be still, and know that I am God! I will be exalted among the nations, I will be exalted in the earth!","Beauty for ashes"];
var rank=0;

// Code for Chrome, Safari and Opera
document.getElementById("myTypewriter").addEventListener("webkitAnimationEnd", changeTxt);

// Standard syntax
document.getElementById("myTypewriter").addEventListener("animationend", changeTxt);

function changeTxt(e){
  _h1 = this.getElementsByTagName("h1")[0];
  _h1.style.webkitAnimation = 'none'; // set element animation to none
   setTimeout(function() { // you surely want a delay before the next message appears
      _h1.innerHTML=messages[rank];
      var speed =2.8*messages[rank].length/20; // adjust the speed (3.5 is the original speed, 20 is the original string length
      _h1.style.webkitAnimation = 'typing '+speed+'s steps(40, end), blink-caret .75s step-end infinite'; //  switch to the original set of animation      
      (rank===messages.length-1)?rank=0:rank++; // if you have displayed the last message from the array, go back to the first one, else go to next message
    }, 1000);
}
```

```css
body{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    background-color: purple;
}
.cf:before,
.cf:after {
    content: " ";
    display: table;
}
.cf:after {
    clear: both;
}
/*-------------Header/Nav----------*/
header{
 width: 100%;
}
#start{
 width: 90%;
 margin: 0 auto;
  text-align: center;
}
#start h1{
 color: white;
    letter-spacing:6px;
 font-size: 3em;
 font-family: 'Anton', sans-serif;
}
nav ul{
 list-style-type: none;
 padding: 0;
 margin-left: 32%;
}
nav a{
    float: left;
 font-size: 1.2em;
 margin-right: 38px;
}
#wrapper{
    width: 100%;
    margin: 0 auto;
    background-color: Fuchsia;
    color:white;
}
#nav{
 width: 80%;
 margin: 0 auto;
}
a:nth-child{
 margin-right: 0;
}
/**************Type writer***********/
.myTypewriter h1 {
  overflow: hidden; /* Ensures the content is not revealed until the animation */
  border-right: .15em solid orange; /* The typwriter cursor */
  white-space: nowrap; /* Keeps the content on a single line */
  margin: 0 auto; /* Gives that scrolling effect as the typing happens */
  letter-spacing: .15em;
   /* Adjust as needed */
  animation: 
  typing 3.5s steps(40, end),
  blink-caret .75s step-end infinite;
}
#wrapper-two{
  background: purple;
  color: #fff;
  font-family: monospace;
  padding-top: 3em;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}
@keyframes typing {
  from { width: 0 }
  to { width: 100% }
}
/* The typewriter cursor effect */
@keyframes blink-caret {
  from, to { border-color: transparent }
  50% { border-color: blue; }
}
/*--------------section two---------------*/
#wrapper-home{
 width: 90%;
 margin:0 auto;
  display: -webkit-flex;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    align-items: stretch;
}
h2{
 float: left;
}
img{
 float: left;
}
/*----------------Media Queries-----------*/
@media only screen and (max-width: 1200px){
nav ul{
 margin-left: 20%
}
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head> 
 <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="otkcdim.css">
 <title>Home</title>
</head>
<body>
   <header>
 <div id="start">
  <h1>Only </h1>
 </div>
   </header>
  <nav >
  <div id="wrapper" class="cf">
    <div id="nav" class="cf">
   <ul class="cf">
    <li><a>Home</a></li>
    <li><a>About Us</a></li>
    <li><a>Events</a></li>
    <li><a>Encouragement</a></li>
    <li><a>Contact Us</a></li>
   </ul>
       </div>
      </div>
  </nav>
     <!--*****************Type Writer*************************-->
  <section>
   <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <div id="wrapper-two">
    <div class="myTypewriter" id="myTypewriter">
   <h1> Beauty for Ashes</h1>
    </div>
 </div>
  </section>
    <!--**********Home Page***************--> 
     <div id="wrapper-home">
      <div class="yes">
        <img src="ma.jpg">
        <h2>Welcome.</h2> 
       </div>
     </div>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="otkcdim.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I made a small change to your CSS to fix this problem. Hope it's helpful.

```
.myTypewriter h1 {
  overflow: hidden; 
  border-right: .15em solid orange; /* The typwriter cursor */
  white-space: nowrap; /* Keeps the content on a single line */
  margin: 0 auto; /* Gives that scrolling effect as the typing happens */
  letter-spacing: .15em;

  // Set minimum height of auto-typewriter to hold it's place even when empty. 
  min-height: 25px;


   /* Adjust as needed */
  animation: 

  typing 3.5s steps(40, end),
  blink-caret .75s step-end infinite;
}
```